# Big O calculation for a function

Tags: loops, big-o

How to calculate O for a function?

I need to know the O of this function. (and each of the loops)

```
int find_c(int n)
  int i,j,c
  for(i=n*n; i > 1; i=i/4) //O(logn)
    for(j=n*n; j > n/2; j--) //?
      c++
  for(i=c; i > 0; i--) //O(c)
    if(random(0...99) > 0) //O(1)
      for(j=n; j > 0; j--) //O(n)
        c++ //O(1)
    else
      for(j=400; j > 1; j--) //O(400)?
        c++ //O(1)
  return c
```

Comment: Have you even tried doing this on your own? If so at least post some thoughts of yours or partial solution. For example `c++` is obviously `O(1)`. Same could probably be said about the execution of `random(0...99)`.

Comment: I have tried this myself but I don't know if my answers are correct. are all if/else parts O(1)*inner-O?

Comment: `if` and `else` in itself don't do a think. Its the logical expression inside the `if` that matters. If you have `if(a == 2)` or similar you have `O(1)` however if you compare strings inside that `if` things are different and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int find_c(int n)
  int i,j,c
  for(i=n*n; i > 1; i=i/4) //O(logn)
    for(j=n*n; j > n/2; j--) //O(n2)
      c++   //c = O(n2.logn)
  for(i=c; i > 0; i--) //O(n2.logn)
    if(random(0...99) > 0) //O(1)
      for(j=n; j > 0; j--) //O(n)
        c++ //O(1)  //c = O(n3logn)
    else
      for(j=400; j > 1; j--) //O(1)
        c++ //c = O(n2log2)
  return c
```

So the final answer is O(n^3.log n)

Comment: in the first for loop, does c value = O(logn * n^2)? And later you use that c value whenever it loops c times ye?

Comment: Yes, this is in the comments